# How to remove link to product page from woocommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried adding

> remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item',
>   'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
>
> remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item',
>   'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );

in theme functions.php file.

Its not worked for me.

I just want to prevent users to reach product page. So i have to remove links from shop page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have solution, dirty one. But it'll be working perfect.
Copy of content-product.php and paste it into the root of your theme folder.

Comment out

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
```

and

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! But its broke all of page and images and i can click product name so its redirect to product page :(

Comment: /your-child-theme/woocommerce/content-product.php

Comment: and edit link https://www.skyverge.com/blog/woocommerce-remove-link-to-product-page/

Comment: @Alper: I had tested and worked fine for me. Remove woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title, for removing title too.

Comment: Thanks for your response, as i said on first post. it's didn't work for me and im using woocommerce 2.6.x

Answer (score 0):

I have another one:
check css class for this link (Firefox F12 or right mouse button on link and show source) and add in css:

```
.css-link-class-name{display: none !important}
```

or search in google:

https://www.skyverge.com/blog/woocommerce-remove-link-to-product-page/

Comment: Thanks for your response! But it's just hide. I just want to remove link from Product name and İmage so users can't go product page

Comment: Thanks for your response, as i said on first post. it's didn't work for me and im using woocommerce 2.6.x

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it worked for me!!!

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded','your_function_name' );
function your_function_name() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open' );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close' );
}
```