# Removing Woocommerce product link & Single product page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a woocommerce shop(Astra theme) with Elementor. Now I have some products, but when you click those product you go to the Single product page of that specific product. I want to remove the link from the product & don't want to go to the single product page.

What I have tried is: Creating A section with the class "items"(All products are in this section). Within that class I added this CSS to hide the A tag from the woocommerce product but it doesn't work.

```
.items .woocommerce-loop-product__title a{
pointer-events: none !important; 
cursor: default !important; }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove link to single page from Woocommerce product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56336451/remove-link-to-single-page-from-woocommerce-product-page)

Answer (score 4):

**USING CSS**

The use of a CSS rule cannot be universal but varies according to the theme used.

This way you are only disabling the title link but not the one on the image *(there are more links in the product box)*.

> I use the Storefront theme.

Try this to remove the link to the product page except the *Add to cart* button:

```
body.archive .woocommerce-loop-product__link {
    pointer-events: none; 
    cursor: default;
}
```

Try this instead to remove the link to the entire product box *(also to the Add to Cart button)*:

```
body.archive ul.products li {
    pointer-events: none; 
    cursor: default;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's stylesheet.*

**USING PHP**

The loop product permalink is created via the [**`woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-template-functions.html#source-view.1189) function of WooCommerce.

In `/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php` you find the hooks:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
```

So to remove product page links you can use this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
```

*Add these two lines to your active theme's functions.php.*

> If that doesn't work for you either, the theme you are using most
> likely overrides the link creation function. In this case you should
> check your theme's template files or contact support directly.

Other helpful answers:

- [Remove Woocommerce product link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215124/remove-woocommerce-product-link)
- [How to remove link to product page from woocommerce shop page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999532/how-to-remove-link-to-product-page-from-woocommerce-shop-page)
- [Remove link to single page from Woocommerce product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56336451/remove-link-to-single-page-from-woocommerce-product-page)
- [WooCommerce: Disable Link to Single Product @ Shop](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-disable-link-to-product-loop/)